# Convert int to *NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, warnings

When using this

```
NSInteger *myInteger = 45 ;
```

I get the warning message `Incompatible Integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to parameter of type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *')`
I have read another posts with same warning but did not find proper solution.

Comment: You can't name a variable `int`, it's reserved...

Comment: replace *int with some variable name such as a,x, or any other which you want

Comment: yeah .. i realized it later .. didnt give much attention to the variable name while posting the question. was more focused on the warning generated. have corrected it avoid any confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSInteger` is not a subclass of `NSObject` as it might seem, it's a primitive type. Change your code to:

```
NSInteger a = 45 ;
```

And (of course) do not name your variable int

Comment: thanks for your response.sorry my bad for choosing the wrong example.

Answer (score 1):

You should use different name then int because it is a name for a special primitive type integer. Like that you cannot name a variable with names like for, while, void... Just use another name(and you should name it to understand what it holds) like:

```
NSInteger myFirstInteger = 45;
```

Note: In your future projects, please name your variables with a meaningful name ,so that you can create a meaningful piece of code which is easy to understand and improve.

Comment: This is incorrect, an NSInteger should not be a pointer. Remove the asterisk before `myFirstInteger`.

Comment: True, I editted my answer. I thought I was writing about NSNumber my fault thanks for the correction.